# Save/Load workspace in C++ application

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I'm working on adding a new feature to an existing program.  It's basically a save/load workspace feature, where a user can save the positions of their windows, and then load said positions whenever they want to by selecting a menu item.  In order to implement this, I have created code which extracts the screen coordinates of the window and writes them to a file (below) :

```
void CMainFrame::SaveWorkspace()
{

RECT ctrlsize;
m_pDialog->GetWindowRect((LPRECT)&ctrlsize);  //obtains location for window
ofstream Workspace("saveone", ios::out);
Workspace << ctrlsize.left << "," << ctrlsize.top << "," << ctrlsize.right << "," << ctrlsize.bottom;

}
```

And this (is supposed to) loads the workspace:

```
void CMainFrame::LoadWorkspace()
{

 //Read in the data from the file
int data[3][4];
int r=0;
int a=0;
int b=0;

ifstream infile;

infile.open("saveone");
for(a = 0; a< 3; a++)
{
for(b = 0;b<4;b++)
{
  infile >> data[a][b];
  cout << data[a][b];
}
}


infile.close();

//Now, assign the extracted values
RECT ctrlset;

ctrlset.top = data[0][1];
ctrlset.left = data[0][0];
ctrlset.right = data[2][0];
ctrlset.bottom = data[0][3];
// Finally, reassign the window positions

m_pDialog->SetWindowPos(NULL, ctrlset.left, ctrlset.top, (ctrlset.right - ctrlset.left),     (ctrlset.bottom - ctrlset.top), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

}
```

Problems:

1) the SaveWorkspace function works sporadically; more often than not, it doesn't create a file.
2) the LoadWorkspace function doesn't work.  Specifically, only the data[0][0] coordinate gets saved to the array (the first value in the file).

This seems like a fairly easy thing to do, I'm a bit embarrassed that it's giving me so much trouble...

EDIT:  I've fixed problem #1.  Now I just need to figure out why my array isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two problems in the reading.

1. Your array definition is wrong. It is :

   data[2][3];

This has only 6 values.
However, in the loop you are reading 12 values out.

1. You have the "," values in the file. You are not getting rid of them.
   Maybe as an easy solution, you could add a new line after each entry when you write them.
   Or you could enter the details of a single rectangle on one line, then read the full line and parse for the individual components yourself.

Comment: Yep, just figured it out; the >> operator doesn't recognize commas.  changed the ',' to ' ' and it works.  thanks!